# .htaccess mod rewrite folder to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, directory

So I have the main photos folder and I want to make it subdomain style
so there is /images/ and /images/thumbs. What I'm trying to accomplish
is 'converting'

```
/images/ -> images.domain.com
```

and

```
/images/thumbs -> thumbs.domain.com
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumbs/(.*)$  http://thumbs.domain.com/$1
RewriteRule ^/?images/(.*)$   http://images.domain.com/$1  [L]
```

This rules rewrite URLs like: `http://domain.com/images/lol.png`  to `http://images.domain.com/lol.png`.
And: `http://domain.com/images/thumbs/lol.png` to `http://thumbs.domain.com/lol.png`.
 **With no external redirect.**

Comment: Thanks have you tested it? I cant seem to access images.domain.com
I also have enabled Options -Indexes does it affect this? Does it work on a typical shared server (im using HG).
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can't test that :-D that option has no effect on these rule but both domains should have save server & IP